# how to remove an element from a nested list lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

could you please help me to solve a tricky homework about nested list? 
Basically anytime the predicate evenp is true , I should remove the element from the list (or from the nested list) keeping the structure of the whole list.

```
(Nopred 'evenp '(1 S d ((4)) (7) ((((8)))) u))
```

It should return

```
(1 S d (()) (7) (((()))) u)
```

This is the function I wrote

```
(Defun nopred (f list)
  (Cond ((null list))
        ((Symbolp (car list)) (cons (car list) (nopred f  (cdr list)))
         ((Listp  (car list)) (cons (nopred f ( car list)) (nopred f (cdr list))))
         ((Funcall f (car list)) (nopred f (cdr list)))
         (T (cons (car list) (nopred f (cdr list))))))
```

I tried to solve with this code but it doesn't work, it does not remove the element when evenp is true and it returns values like

```
((((5 .T ) .).).)
```

Comment: Is `(cdr l)` a copying error? Shouldn't it be `(cdr list)`?

Comment: When the indentation is corrected, you can see the problem. You're missing a `)` at the end of the `Symbolp` line, so all that code is treated as part of that case. But that should be causing errors, so I suspect it's another copying error. Post the actual code, with proper indentation, otherwise we can't tell what's really wrong.

Comment: Special treatment of symbols seems wrong ideologically. I understand that this is to avoid errors on `(evenp S)` &c, but this is still wrong.

Comment: Thanks for answering @sds but I don't get what do you mean , the case is pretty simple and obvious , if the element in the list is a symbolp then I put in list and check the next one , going on the cdr . Instead what im not pretty sure if is it right (funcall f (car l)) , as far I understood , it applies the function to the arg . Thanks

Comment: @MaxMnt: what if your function `f` does something interesting on symbols? (e.g., checks their home package) your `nopred` will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return `NIL` in the `(null list)` case. When you don't have a return value in the matching `COND` clause, it returns the value of the condition, and `(null list)` returns `T`.

You also had some typos in the posted code: `(cdr l)` should have been `(cdr list)`, and there was a missing `)` at the end of that line.

```
(defun nopred (f list)
  (cond ((null list) nil)
        ((symbolp (car list)) (cons (car list) (nopred f  (cdr list))))
        ((listp  (car list)) (cons (nopred f ( car list)) (nopred f (cdr list))))
        ((funcall f (car list)) (nopred f (cdr list)))
        (t (cons (car list) (nopred f (cdr list))))))
```

With these corrections I get the correct result:

```
(1 S d (nil) (7) (((nil))) u)
```

Comment: Thanks @barmar for the answer,  probably I did some some mistakes copying the code . (using smartphones to write codes is not that much comfortable). Anyways , I thought that writing the cond ( (null list )nil ) would give (nil) and (((nil))) as final result which is not right , instead of I should get the empty list once the predicate evenp is true , so something like this ( 1 S d ( ) (7) ((( ))) u) . Another question, is it right (funcall f (arg)) , as far I understood funcall apply the f to the arg. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @MaxMnt `()` and `nil` is just different ways to write the same object and the repl printer will only print it one way. You might want a list of symbols like `'(t nil x y)` or you want nestes lists, some which are empty `'(t () x y)` however these are the same in terms of `equal`: `(equal '(t nil x y) '(t () x y)) ; ==> t`

Comment: @Sylwester yeah, i totally agree what you said. but in this case , the result has to be with this representation -> ( ) instead of Nil.
so the output should be -> ( 1 ( ) 3 d ((( ))) ) 
i tried to replace Nil with cons '( ') or append '( ( ) '( ) ) but it does not work.
actually this is a kind of questions of my next Lisp exam at university , thus i'm looking for a way to solve this proble with 'nil' .
thanks.

Comment: @MaxMnt There is no problem. The printer displays `nil` for `nil` and not `()` and as long as you use the structure as result it will show it like that. You can make a string representation of the structure or your own print function that prints `nil` as `()` but it's just how things are visualized and doesn't really change the fact that the result without doing this is correct. You have the same if you use pairs as binary tree structure and want it displayed like `'((leaf . leaf) . (leaf . leaf))` which the standard printer always will display as `((leaf . leaf) leaf . leaf)`.

Comment: @Sylwester  Yeah , i get what you say. In fact if it was for me I would leave the code as it is right now. But since the is one of the minimal requirements to pass the exam , I'm still up to find a solution of the output. The thing is that everything has to be in only one function , so the print does not work that much and at the I would have (list ) and the nil as result of printing. Could you please help me out to find the solution? I tried to replace nil with ( ) but it doesn't , I mean I does but only as a string "( ) " which is not allow in the exercise.

Comment: @MaxMnt If the function is to return a list then it does. How the REPL chooses to display an empty list has nothing to do with your function and it might even be implementation dependant as well as user setting dependent what your teachers will see when the structure gets printed and there is nothing you can do to "fix" that. You are asking how to get any lisp system to print `()` when you enter `()` in the REPL. It can be done, but not chosen by the thing that is to be displayed or the function that made the structure.

Comment: @Sylwester thanks a lot for helping me with the topic!. In these case i will not be worry about the final output, actually if the program does what it has to do , that's enough for the exam.
Thanks again.
Cheers!